# Placing a drupal menu on an external site

Tags: routes, external-scripts

I have a drupal install (latest 7.x version at the time of writing). It is in the root directory of my domain.

In a non drupal sub-directory, called 'member' so at /member, I have 3rd party script which enables my site to have membership functionality.

The script inside of /member is not drupal, although it does connect to the drupal database to write to the users table to enable single sign-on.

I was wondering if it is possible to display a drupal menu (the main navigation) inside the script in /member? I want to be able to alter the menu in drupal and then have those alterations automatically updated in the /member script.

I would certainly appreciate any advise as to whether this is in fact possible, and some advice about how I might get started.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
In your drupal website:

- Render the main menu block on a custom made (module) page for example /main-menu-external
- Strip all the sections but the content section, so that no header, footer, ... is rendered, only the menu.
- With context load a blank theme on the page "main-menu-external"
- At this point "main-menu-external" will be a blanco page with only the main menu rendered on it AND will use a different theme from the rest of your website so you can configure it for that page only.

In your /members website:

- Just put an `<iframe>` with source "yourdrupalwebsite.be/main-menu-external"

Et voila, there is your drupal menu on an external website :)

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your idea. I have a further question if that's okay. Does using an <iframe> mean that I would be unable to serve pages securely using an SSL? Would this external (from a different script albeit simply from a subdirectory) <iframe> make the EV SSL display a warning?

Comment: I don't know that. But I was thinking, maybe you can use the services module and this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/services_menu to implement your external menu? Let me know if this works. I will add it as an answer

Comment: Using your context idea above, what do you mean by 'load a blank theme' via context? Sorry, I cannot understand how to achieve this with context. I'm afraid that I might well need some more hand holding!

Comment: After some digging, you will have to use function `mymodule_custom_theme() {
  if (arg(0) == 'event2011') {
    return 'the theme to use for that page';
  }
}`

to load a blank theme on the page where your menu is located